# add dynamic values to a text in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

using java script i need to add dynamic values to a text contained in the html.

In the following code i nee to print the Screenshot based on the `count 0,1,2 like` that

```
var html="";

 for(var i=0; i<count;i++){
                html += ' <a target="_blank" href="/test.html">Screenshot</a><br>';
            }
       errEl.html(html);

eg: Screenshot_0
Screenshot_1
Screenshot_2
```

how can made changes in the code  `html += ' <a target="_blank" href="/test.html">Screenshot</a><br>';`

Answer (score 2):

The text is just a string, so you can perform string concatenation with `+`:

```
for(var i=0; i<count;i++){
    html += ' <a target="_blank" href="/test.html">Screenshot ' + i + '</a><br>';
}
```